# USB disk partitions disappeared, cannot mount

Tags: partition, usb, usb-drive, fdisk

The USB partitions were deleted, only sdb remained. sdb1 does not exist. How do I partition the USB again? Now it shows up in the `lsblk` output, but I can't mount it.

```
[xx@x ~]$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda3   8:3    0 457.3G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   1   7.2G  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
[xx@x ~]$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.39).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.
```

When I plug in the normal working usb `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb`
When I run the command, the commands I can use appear. For example the `m` command works.

The n command is not used.  When fdisk /dev/sdb runs, it gives an input/output error after a certain time.

```
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: Input/Output error
```

dmesg:

```
[10846.218694] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 60864 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 30 prio class 2
[10846.218706] buffer_io_error: 7 callbacks suppressed
[10846.218710] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 7608, lost async page write
[10846.218726] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 7609, lost async page write
[10846.218733] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 7610, lost async page write
[10846.218739] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 7611, lost async page write
[10846.218744] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 7612, lost async page write
[10846.218750] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 7613, lost async page write
[10846.218754] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 7614, lost async page write
[10846.218760] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 7615, lost async page write
[10846.218765] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 7616, lost async page write
[10846.218769] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 7617, lost async page write
[10852.869745] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[10859.734626] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
```

when first hooked up:

```
[12538.293232] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0930, idProduct=6544, bcdDevice= 1.00
[12538.293246] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[12538.293250] usb 3-2: Product: TransMemory     
[12538.293253] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: TOSHIBA 
[12538.293256] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 307135823CDACE709B1D1E25
[12538.294235] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[12538.294463] scsi host6: usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[12539.489418] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  TransMemory      1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[12539.490125] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 15148608 512-byte logical blocks: (7.76 GB/7.22 GiB)
[12539.490389] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[12539.490398] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 45 00 00 00
[12539.490643] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
```

Comment: well, you'll need to `n   add a new partition` for example, to create a new partition?

Comment: @JaromandaX The n command is not used.  When fdisk /dev/sdb runs, it gives an input/output error after a certain time.

Comment: looks like your harddrive/usb-stick is broken. There should be corresponding errors in the kernel-output (dmesg) or logfiles.

Comment: you never mentioned any errors ... I'm confused

Comment: Now I'm trying to reset the content with dd but it doesn't work. And I saw an error in dmesg

**Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 7564, lost async page write**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in your `dmesg` output:

> ```
> [10846.218694] I/O error, dev sdb, sector 60864 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 30 prio class 2
> [10846.218706] buffer_io_error: 7 callbacks suppressed
> [10846.218710] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 7608, lost async page write
> ```

...

There is something **physically wrong with this USB disk**. No way around it.

If you need recovery, you would have to ask for some professional service around.

Comment: Thank you. No matter what I did I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: @alaylihacker There is likely no cheap solution to it. Professional recovery would cost much money, so I did just mention it without elaborating. Cheers. Good luck.